# How do Thunder Hooves Rage and charge interact?

Tags: dnd-4e, charge

*Thunder Hooves Rage* says:

> You enter the rage of the thunder hooves. Until the rage ends, you can move through one or two enemies’ spaces during each of your turns. When you move through an enemy’s space, your next attack against that enemy during the same turn deals `1[W]` extra damage.

*Charge* says:

> The creature moves up to its speed toward the target. Each square of movement must bring the creature closer to the target, and the creature must end the move at least 2 squares away from its starting position.

**How do these two rules interact?**  If I charge a monster three spaces away, I can move three spaces to move into the enemy's space, but then I can't charge away from the monster, right? And you can't end up on the same space as the monster -- you must move through it.

Comment: Did they nerf *Thunder Hooves*?  That's not the way our Barbarian played it ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Extremely poorly. If you charge an enemy three squares away, the normal charge rules apply.**

Thunder hooves rage is not designed for chargers for the exact reasons you just raised. Instead, the rage is designed to work with Pressing Strike which allows shifting through enemy squares.

Swift Panther rage is a better bet for charging barbarians.

Answer (score 0):

the word that I see as breaking this interaction is here: "...you can move **through** one or two..."

I consider there to be a distinction between "through" and "into" in that through requires you to move out of the space after moving into it. because you cannot do this as part of a charge, you cannot enter the enemy space with a charge.

the only exception I can find for this is if you charge through an enemy space and out the other side to hit a second enemy two spaces behind the first. then you'd need an extra action to turn around and hit the first enemy in order to trigger that damage bonus.